# FastAPI - Add description for path parameter in swagger

Tags: fastapi

Imagine there is an app like that:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/items/{item_id}")
async def read_item(item_id: int):
    return {"item_id": item_id}
```

How could one add description for path parameter `item_id` in swagger?

Comment: Does `item_id: int = Path(..., description="An id representing an item")` do what you're looking for?

Comment: @MatsLindh, yes) Please post it as answer. I will accept it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can add description *for a specific* parameter by using the `description` argument to the parameter type object:

```
item_id: int = Path(..., description="An id representing an item")
```

The `...` represents the default value and should be included*.

Edit*: The current version of FastAPI throws an error if `...` is included for `Path` objects, so leave it out if you're using a recent (2023) version.

Comment: I tried this and got an error that said path parameters cannot have default values, so try removing the default value if this doesn't work for you.

Comment: Ah, yes, that was made an error in the latest FastAPI release. Remove it if you're using 0.95+ (iirc.)

Answer (score 3):

Like this

```py
@app.get("/items/{item_id}")
async def read_item(item_id: int):
    """
    item_id: Your item ID description will be here
    """
    return {"item_id": item_id}
```

swagger doc
[image]

Comment: This is not specific to the parameter item_id but to the function

Comment: obviously, it is just as an example.