# Descriptions for endpoints in Swagger for Plumber API

Tags: r, swagger, swagger-ui, documentation-generation, plumber

The [documentation for block annotations for Plumber endpoints](https://www.rplumber.io/articles/annotations.html#endpoint-block-annotations) in R states the following about comments without an annotation:

> First line without annotation will be mapped to Summary field subsequent lines will be mapped to Description field.

I would like to add a more elaborate description for my endpoint, but the result is not as I expected. This is illustrated using the following very basic example.

```
library(plumber)

#* @apiTitle Plumber Example API
#* @apiDescription Plumber example description.

#* This is the summary.
#* 
#* This should be a description (if I understand correctly). 
#* @param msg The message to echo
#* @get /echo
function(msg = "") {
    list(msg = paste0("The message is: '", msg, "'"))
}
```

Running this API results in the following in the Swagger UI:
[image: Swagger documentation of endpoint]

There does not seem to be a distinction between summary and description. The description (highlighted) is rendered on a single line with the summary in the resulting Swagger UI. Based on [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71407405/14440989), which does not use Plumber, I would expect the description to end up between the summary and the "Parameters" section as marked in red.

Am I misunderstanding the documentation or not applying it correctly? Or is this a bug in Plumber?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your example for me it always works out

Comment: @thomas, so you are saying that if you run the code above, you do get a description in the Swagger UI? I would be curious to see what that looks like and why this does not work for me.

Comment: When I am back in my Computer next week I will send a picture. Perhaps there isbsome misconfiguration with Line endings.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/KOb12nb shows the api inside swagger. Sorry for the late answer...

Comment: @thomas, no worries. This is exactly what I expected it to look like. So, my guess is that it is related to the package version. I am using 1.1.0. in this particular case.

Comment: @thomas , I now tried with the latest update (1.2.1) and it is working as expected. I went through the change log and see that this feature was implemented in 1.2.0 (see https://www.rplumber.io/news/index.html#breaking-changes-1-2-0). Sorry for the confusion and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this feature is only supported as of version [1.2.0](https://www.rplumber.io/news/index.html#breaking-changes-1-2-0). So, the documentation I was looking at did not match the package version...