# Why does providing a description for a path parameter causes a 422 error in FastAPI?

Tags: swagger, fastapi

I am learning FastAPI (version 0.104.1). I love the fact that it can automatically generate documentation and testing pages for your API. However, I'm stuck on one thing right now.

Here's the definition for an API endpoint:

```
   @app.get('/api/v1/book/<id>', 
            responses={
               200: {"model":Book,"description":"Details for the requested book"},
               404: {"model":None,"description":"The book could not be found"}
            })
   def get_book(id: str):
      """Gets the details for one specific book."""
      pass # implementation goes here
```

This API endpoint works exactly as expected. However, I want to be able to document the meaning of the parameter in such a way that it shows up in the API documentation page. One [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71400788/fastapi-add-description-for-path-parameter-in-swagger) suggests this might work:

```
   @app.get('/api/v1/book/<id>', 
            responses={
               200: {"model":Book,"description":"Details for the requested book"},
               404: {"model":None,"description":"The book could not be found"}
            })
   def get_book(id: str = Path(..., description="The book ID to retrieve")):
      """Gets the details for one specific book.""" 
      pass # implementation here
```

This works in terms of the API documentation - the description for the parameter shows up correctly.

[image: Image showing working documentation page]

However, the API no longer works. Calling the API results in the following:

```
    Error: Unprocessable Entity

    Response body
    Download
    {
      "detail": [
        {
          "type": "missing",
          "loc": [
            "path",
            "id"
          ],
          "msg": "Field required",
          "input": null,
          "url": "https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.4/v/missing"
        }
      ]
```

So, I found [this page](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/reference/parameters/) in the FastAPI docs and tried using its strategy:

```
   @app.get('/api/v1/book/<id>', 
            responses={
               200: {"model":Book,"description":"Details for the requested book"},
               404: {"model":None,"description":"The book could not be found"}
            })
   def get_book(id = Annotated[str, Path(description="The book ID to retrieve")]):
      """Gets the details for one specific book.""" 
      pass # implementation here
```

Now the API works again, but the description is gone from the documentation pages.

I do not understand how the documentation generator extracts this metadata from the code, and how I can have both the description of the parameter in the docs and also have the parameter work properly.

Answer (score 1):

I was either looking at incorrect documentation or it just literally slipped past my consciousness and my muscle memory from Flask kicked in, but FastAPI uses `{` and `}` for path-based parameters, not `<` and `>`.

Changing to:

```
   @app.get('/api/v1/book/{id}', 
            responses={
               200: {"model":Book,"description":"Details for the requested book"},
               404: {"model":None,"description":"The book could not be found"}
            })
   def get_book(id: str = Path(description="The book ID to retrieve")):
      """Gets the details for one specific book.""" 
      pass # implementation here
```

worked perfectly.